# Percona Community Edition and MySql Community Edition gives “InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 0ms”?

Tags: mysql, innodb

> 2017-09-12T19:04:53.549339Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 23911ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=200 and evicted=0, during the time.)

I get this error on Percona Community Edition and MySql Community Edition. Am wondering if this is an issue on the Percona and MySql Community Edition only ... Will upgrading to the Enterprise Edition of MySQL help resolve this issue?

There are a couple of posts out there with suggestions on lowering the innodb_lru_scan_depth from the default 1024 to 256. That doesn't really resolve this issue.  Wonder if anyone has encountered this issue on the Enterprise Edition?

```
[Updating post to include SHOW VARIABLES like 'innodb%']
sql> show variables like 'innodb%';
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                            | Value                  |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| innodb_adaptive_flushing                 | ON                     | 
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm             | 10                     | 
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index               | ON                     | 
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts         | 8                      | 
| innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay          | 150000                 | 
| innodb_api_bk_commit_interval            | 5                      | 
| innodb_api_disable_rowlock               | OFF                    | 
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                 | OFF                    | 
| innodb_api_enable_mdl                    | OFF                    | 
| innodb_api_trx_level                     | 0                      | 
| innodb_autoextend_increment              | 64                     | 
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                 | 1                      | 
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size            | 134217728              | 
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown      | ON                     | 
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now              | OFF                    | 
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct              | 25                     | 
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename              | ib_buffer_pool         | 
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances             | 8                      | 
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort            | OFF                    | 
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup       | ON                     | 
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now              | OFF                    | 
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                  | 53687091200            | 
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size            | 25                     | 
| innodb_change_buffering                  | all                    | 
| innodb_checksum_algorithm                | crc32                  | 
| innodb_checksums                         | ON                     | 
| innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled             | OFF                    | 
| innodb_commit_concurrency                | 0                      | 
| innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct | 5                      | 
| innodb_compression_level                 | 6                      | 
| innodb_compression_pad_pct_max           | 50                     | 
| innodb_concurrency_tickets               | 5000                   | 
| innodb_data_file_path                    | ibdata1:12M:autoextend | 
| innodb_data_home_dir                     |                        | 
| innodb_deadlock_detect                   | ON                     | 
| innodb_default_row_format                | dynamic                | 
| innodb_disable_sort_file_cache           | OFF                    | 
| innodb_doublewrite                       | ON                     | 
| innodb_fast_shutdown                     | 1                      | 
| innodb_file_format                       | Barracuda              | 
| innodb_file_format_check                 | ON                     | 
| innodb_file_format_max                   | Barracuda              | 
| innodb_file_per_table                    | ON                     | 
| innodb_fill_factor                       | 100                    | 
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout              | 1                      | 
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit           | 2                      | 
| innodb_flush_method                      | O_DIRECT               | 
| innodb_flush_neighbors                   | 1                      | 
| innodb_flush_sync                        | ON                     | 
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops                | 30                     | 
| innodb_force_load_corrupted              | OFF                    | 
| innodb_force_recovery                    | 0                      | 
| innodb_ft_aux_table                      |                        | 
| innodb_ft_cache_size                     | 8000000                | 
| innodb_ft_enable_diag_print              | OFF                    | 
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword                | ON                     | 
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                 | 84                     | 
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                 | 3                      | 
| innodb_ft_num_word_optimize              | 2000                   | 
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit             | 2000000000             | 
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table          |                        | 
| innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree                | 2                      | 
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size               | 640000000              | 
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table            |                        | 
| innodb_io_capacity                       | 15000                  | 
| innodb_log_files_in_group                | 2                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir                | ./                     |
| innodb_log_write_ahead_size              | 8192                   |
| innodb_lru_scan_depth                    | 256                    |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct               | 75.000000              |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm           | 0.000000               |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                     | 0                      |
| innodb_max_purge_lag_delay               | 0                      |
| innodb_max_undo_log_size                 | 1073741824             |
| innodb_monitor_disable                   |                        |
| innodb_monitor_enable                    |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset                     |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset_all                 |                        |
| innodb_numa_interleave                   | OFF                    |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct                    | 37                     |
| innodb_old_blocks_time                   | 1000                   |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size         | 134217728              |
| innodb_open_files                        | 400                    |
| innodb_optimize_fulltext_only            | OFF                    |
| innodb_page_cleaners                     | 4                      |
| innodb_page_size                         | 16384                  |
| innodb_print_all_deadlocks               | OFF                    |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                  | 300                    |
| innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency     | 128                    |
| innodb_purge_threads                     | 4                      |
| innodb_random_read_ahead                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold              | 56                     |
| innodb_read_io_threads                   | 4                      |
| innodb_read_only                         | OFF                    |
| innodb_replication_delay                 | 0                      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout               | OFF                    |
| innodb_rollback_segments                 | 128                    |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size                  | 1048576                |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay                   | 6                      |
| innodb_stats_auto_recalc                 | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_include_delete_marked       | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_method                      | nulls_equal            |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_persistent                  | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages     | 20                     |
| innodb_stats_sample_pages                | 8                      |
| innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages      | 8                      |
| innodb_status_output                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_status_output_locks               | OFF                    |
| innodb_strict_mode                       | ON                     |
| innodb_support_xa                        | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_array_size                   | 1                      |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                   | 30                     |
| innodb_table_locks                       | ON                     |
| innodb_temp_data_file_path               | ibtmp1:12M:autoextend  |
| innodb_thread_concurrency                | 16                     |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay                | 0                      |
| innodb_tmpdir                            |                        |
| innodb_undo_directory                    | ./                     |
| innodb_undo_log_truncate                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_undo_logs                         | 128                    |
| innodb_undo_tablespaces                  | 0                      |
| innodb_use_native_aio                    | ON                     |
| innodb_version                           | 5.7.18                 |
| innodb_write_io_threads                  | 16                     |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: I suspect there is no code difference in this area for Community versus Enterprise.

Comment: Thank you, Rick. Ever encountered the above error? Any tested and working solutions to this issue?

Comment: No.  Can you give details of what was going on at the time?

Comment: Yes sure ... a whole bunch of inserts into the tables triggers the issue of delayed database writes. I tried changing the following in the .cnf file: innodb_lru_scan_depth = 256, innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0  ... didn't resolve.

Comment: What drives - HDD or SSD?  What values for `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';` ?  Are the inserts scattered around the tables?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- mostly want to see index(es).  Let's see a typical `INSERT(s)`.

Comment: Drive used is SSD.  There is no index defined on the table.

Comment: The inserts are in batch. A typical INSERT looks like ..   create table 'table_name' (
 'ID' mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 'TIME_SEC' int(11)  NOT NULL,
 'TIME_MS smallint(6) NOT NULL,
 'FVALUE' double NOT NULL,
 'RVALUE' double  NOT NULL,
 'CVALUE' varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
 'VALIDITY' tinyint(4)  NOT NULL,
 'OOL_STATE' tinyint(4)  NOT NULL,
 'ACTIVE' tinyint(4)  NOT NULL,
 'TIME_DOUBLE' double  NOT NULL,
 'PRIORITY' tinyint(4)  NOT NULL,
 'PKT' smallint(4)  NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY_KEY ('ID', 'TIME_DOUBLE', 'TIME_MS'),
 key 'i_time_sec' ('TIME_DOUBLE')
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Eh?  That looks more like a `CREATE TABLE` than an `INSERT`.

Comment: And the `SHOW`?

Comment: Sorry, the above is the SHOW CREATE TABLE and not the INSERT.

Comment: Its kind of hard to post the SHOW VARIABLES here as it makes the post too long ... is there any way to attach to this post?

Comment: The limited `SHOW` that I requested is only about 140 lines.  The full `SHOW VARIABLES` is more like 500, and would need some free site like post.it.  If you do that, please also provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` so I can provide more info.  Also, how much RAM do you have?

Comment: RAM is 64GB. innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 80% of the RAM.

Comment: @Rick: I have updated the post to include the output for show variables like 'innodb%'. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

(Not an Answer, but some info and links from changelogs)
(Links are relative to dev.mysql.com)

----- 2015-08-03 5.7.8 Release Candidate -- Functionality Added or Changed -- InnoDB -----

The default value for innodb_purge_threads ( /doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_purge_threads ) and innodb_page_cleaners ( /doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_cleaners ) was changed from 1 to 4. If the number of page cleaner threads exceeds the number of buffer pool instances, innodb_page_cleaners ( /doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_cleaners ) is automatically set to the same value as innodb_buffer_pool_instances ( /doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances ).

----- 2014-09-25 5.7.5 Milestone 15 -- Functionality Added or Changed -- InnoDB -----

For optimal shutdown and recovery performance, shutdown and recovery phases are now supported by the multi-threaded page cleaner feature (innodb_page_cleaners ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_cleaners )) that was introduced in MySQL 5.7.4. (Bug #18805275)

----- 2014-03-31 5.7.4 Milestone 14 -- Functionality Added or Changed -- InnoDB,Performance -----

InnoDB now supports multiple page_cleaner threads for flushing dirty pages from buffer pool instances. A new system variable, innodb_page_cleaners, is used to specify the number of page_cleaner threads. The default value of 1 maintains the pre-MySQL 5.7.4 configuration in which there is only a single page_cleaner thread. This enhancement builds on work completed in MySQL 5.6.2, which introduced a single page cleaner thread to offload buffer pool flushing work from the InnoDB master thread.

----- 2011-10-03 5.6.3 Milestone 6 -- Functionality Added or Changed -- InnoDB,Performance -----

Work continues to offload flush ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_flush ) operations from the InnoDB main thread, doing them in the page_cleaner thread instead. The latest changes to the buffer pool flushing algorithms can improve performance for some I/O-bound workloads, particularly in configurations with multiple buffer pool instances. You control this feature by adjusting the settings for the innodb_lru_scan_depth ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lru_scan_depth ) and innodb_flush_neighbors ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_neighbors ) configuration options. To find the optimal settings, test each combination of the above settings with both the Adaptive Hash Index ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_adaptive_hash_index ) and the Doublewrite Buffer ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_doublewrite_buffer ) turned on and off. See Tuning InnoDB Buffer Pool Flushing ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-lru-background-flushing.html ) for more details.

=======

Recommend reading the article on background-flushing and clicking `Affects me` on any relevant bugs in bugs.mysql.com, such as
[81899](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81899) and/or 
[76661](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76661)

Also,...  `innodb_io_capacity` = 15000 seems high, even for SSD.

Comment: Thank you, Rick! I will go through the links above and play around with the various configuration parameters and see. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Rick ... I tried changing several of the parameters in my.cnf. However nothing worked...the issue persists :-( Just wondering if this is a bug in MySQLCommunity Edition .. came across this post - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76661.

Comment: Configuration Changes: 
[09/14] innodb_buffer_pool_size=50GB
 innodb_io_capacity=15000
    innodb_io_capacity_max=25000
 innodb_lru_scan_depth = 256
 innodb_write_io_threads=16         
[09/21]
 innodb_flush_neighbor=0          
[09/22]
 innodb_log_file_size=100GB
 innodb_log_files_in_group=5        
[09/25]
 innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50
 innodb_log_buffer_size=4GB
 innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm=30
 innodb_thread_concurrency=0
 innodb_write_io_threads=64          
[09/26]
 innodb_concurrency_tickets=500
 innodb_lru_scan_depth =512
 innodb_thread_concurrency=16

Comment: what should the innodb_io_capacity be set to?

Comment: Bigger is _not always_ better.  Some of those numbers are reaching into the stratosphere where no one has gone.  `innodb_log_buffer_size = 32M` (else wasting RAM) `innodb_io_capacity = 2000` (since you have SSD) `innodb_log_files_in_group = 2` (more than 2 hurts) `innodb_log_file_size = 3G` (not sure if it works past 4G)

Comment: Suggest filing a bug report about page_cleaner with bugs.mysql.com if it is diff than the one you mentioned.  At least click "Affects me".

Comment: Made the configuration changes as suggested ... the issue remains. Yes, I did click "Affects me".

Comment: Alas, I don't have all the answers.

Comment: Thank you, Rick!! Appreciate all your inputs thus far!

Comment: This issue is not reported in another box with exactly the same configurations (64GB RAM, write-intensive) as the one on which this  issue was reported. Both have MySQL Community Edition 5.7.18. Any further inputs on how to check what is causing this issue on one box and not the other?

Comment: Please provide `SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_METRICS WHERE name LIKE 'buffer_%'
;` -- I'll see if I can get some clues from there.

Comment: Please follow this link to access the innodb_metrics. https://pastebin.com/UpMdHR8n

Comment: At OOW17, someone more knowledgeable than I said that the `page_cleaner` message was just a spurious debugging note.  Not sure what to make of the I_S.

Comment: Even if its just a misleading debug note, am just wondering why it is reported on one box and not the other (both have same configuration)? On box1 where this error is observed, this message appears very often, about every minute or two.

Comment: Can you point me to any link/documentation from OOW17 where the page cleaner message was cited as a spurious debug note?

Comment: @user8604757 - No docs, just a verbal communication.  Why one machine, not another? -- That seems to remain as much a mystery as the note itself.  Sorry.  Search for page_cleaner; you will see that you are not alone.

Comment: Hmmmm ... yeah ... that's what bothers me - reported on one machine and not the other :( Yeah ... I did see a lot of posts out there but no 'working' solution :( Thanks, Rick ... appreciate all your inputs!